# VSCode + Unity: Remembering last/open session when opening script form Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

The Unity game engine ships with Visual Studio Community. I have switched from that to VSCode due to many benefits (for ex full syntax highlighting and autocomplete for any kind of shader file).

I can't get VSCode to reopen my last session when I doubleclick a script from within Unity that launches the default code editor (VSCode).

I have set `"window.restoreWindows": "all",` in VSCode settings. What this does is if I open VSCode from outside unity (e.g. desktop shortcut), it reopens my last open folder / set of files /session as intended.

But if I then open a script from within Unity, this entire VSCode session gets scrapped and only the file I just clicked on shows in VSCode.

I have also installed all the VSCode unity integration extensions.

Any idea what's going on? Can I customize VSCode to append to the existing window session? (get it to behave just like any version of Visual Studio?)

### [EDIT]

I have figured out why this happens! (but don't know how to fix)

In the unity command line args ([docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Preferences.html)) `-n` means go to line Number. Whereas in VSCode ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)) the `-n` means "Opens a new session of VS Code instead of restoring the previous session (default)."

Unity must be, for any doubleclicks, script edits, or error console doubleclicks, calling the external editor with the -n parameter to go to either line 0 or a specific line.

Is it possible to change either how unity parses command line arguments, or how VSCode parses the command line arguments?

### [EDIT2]

Fixed with Diptangshu Chakrabarty's resolved question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550056/unity-opens-multiple-workspaces-when-using-vscode-as-editor/49557370#49557370), and Diptangshu Chakrabarty's answer on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you pass the following as editor argument as see if it works?

> -g "$(File):$(Line)"

Comment: That'd be great, but unfortunately I don't think there is any way to modify the command line args that Unity sends to the external code editor. There used to be a GUI setting for it in old versions some years ago, but no longer.

Comment: I was facing a similar issue and got this answer. Have not been able to try this yet. But I think it should work for you as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49557370/9533015