# Unity opens multiple workspaces when using VSCode as editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I have integrated VSCode with Unity 2017.3.0f3 by following the tutorial given in VSCode [Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity)

I am facing an issue wherein whenever I open a script file from the Unity project explorer, it opens multiple workspace in VSCode. Furthermore, if click *Assets > Open C# Project*, then the number of opened workspace increases the next time I double click to open a file.

Also, I do not see the "External Script Editor Args" settings in *Preferences > External Tools" as described in the Unity [Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Preferences.html).

Has anybody fixed this issue?

Comment: Is this issue fixed? Do you know how to make "External Script Editor Args" appear now?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/vscode-unity-debug/issues/67) which is not yet fixed on the Unity VSCode built-in extension. Read below for a possible fix.

> I do not see the "External Script Editor Args" settings in
>   *Preferences > External Tools" as described in the Unity Doc.

You won't see this if you use one of the build-in Editors displayed in that menu. Create your own.

You need to point *External Script Editor* to an exe file or a batch script in order for the *"External Script Editor Args"* settings to appear.

Create a batch. Name it *vscode.bat*. The code below should be inside of it:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" %*
exit 0
```

Note that `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe` is the path of your VSCode so make sure to substitute your own path there.

Go to *Preferences* > *External Tools*  then select on *Browse* on the *External Script Editor* menu then select the *vscode.bat*.

[image]

When the File Browser pops up, change from "*exe (*.exe)*" to "*All files (*.*)"".

[image]

Select the *vscode.bat* file and click the Open button.

*"External Script Editor Args"* settings should now appear. Use *"$(File)"* in it. Include the *" "* too. This may also solve your multiple workspace problems in your question.

The final image should look this:

[image]

Comment: This relatively old answer helped me to solve (Unity 2020.03.23f1, VSCode 1.62.3). My default "External Script Editor Args" was `"$(ProjectPath)" -g "$(File)":$(Line):$(Column)`  and scripts from Unity were opened into a new workspace. By replacing it with just `"$(File)"` they get opened in an available workspace.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same on macOS, which is a bit more elaborate than the Windows solution @Programmer posted, I am adding it here for completeness sake.

1. Create a `test.sh` file with these lines (of course, make sure your VSCode is at this location)

`nano test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" "$@"
```

2. Now get this handy script, which can create a minimal app from your `test.sh` (this step is needed because Unity on macOS doesn't allow you to select anything other than an `.app` file as the external editor, unlike Windows)

https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099

`./applify test.sh "Test"`

3. After creating your app, make sure it works by trying something like this in Terminal:

`Test.app/Contents/MacOS/Test -r -g /path-to-some-file:10`

4. If it works, then you can set it as an external editor in Unity, and set *External Script Editor Args* field to:

`-r -g "$(File)":$(Line)`

5. Double-click on any scripts and shaders in your Unity project, and it should work.

**That's it, I have verified this to work on my macOS 10.13.4 and Unity 2018.1**

Answer (score 0):

For **Linux** users try edit vscode **.desktop** file:

In this line:

```
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/vscode_vscode.desktop /snap/bin/vscode
```

add **"$@"** at the end:

```
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/vscode_vscode.desktop /snap/bin/vscode "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a Unity file in an existing workspace, as of Unity 2022.3 I found you need to put `-r -g $(File):$(Line):$(Column)` for the external script editor args. (The quotes around `$(File)` in the default caused it to open a new file).